# When to email back after interview

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

I had an in person job interview about a week before Chrstmas.  After the interview, they told me I would be contacted in a week with the company's response and if they didn't get back to me I should contact them.  The only problem was that a week after the interview was christmas.  I haven't heard back and it's been nearly two weeks.  I know the holidays are delaying things, so I'm wondering -

When/If I should contact them (by email I presume) and what should I say?  I want to sound enthusiastic but not nagging.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call them up and say, "Hi, I'm Mr. X who came in for an interview on Dec. 17th. I wanted an update as I haven't heard anything in the past week. How is the process going?"

The key here is that you want an update on the process, you state who you are and when the interview occurred that may help jog the other person's memory as they may not remember you by voice. At the same time, you may end up with voice mail where the idea is the same message applies though I'd probably add my own number to the message in that case so they know what number to call for me.

Comment: I called and got voicemail and left a nice message including my number.  Thanks for the advice!